# How to set Redirect URI for Spring Boot App on App Service using Azure AD

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I followed the below tutorial to deploy a Spring Boot web application locally that uses Azure AD:

https://dev.to/azure/using-spring-security-with-azure-active-directory-mga

This works well locally,and I have deployed the application to Azure App Service. To redirect correctly for Oauth I am configuring the Redirect URI on App Service, the Azure GUI expects an OAuth Redirect URI that begins with "https://" and Spring boot expects a redirect URI with the format "http://[domain]:[port]/login/oauth2/code/azure".

Is there a way to configure Spring to expect a URI beginning with "https://"

I tried updating the below application property which didn't help. There is workaround to use Type=Public client/native with an "http" URI. Is there a better solution?

> spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri-template={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}

Comment: The article link does not work, it's a 404. And https is definitely required. It's allowed for localhost, but not outside that. Authorization codes etc. should not be passed to an insecure endpoint, so it's blocked.

Comment: But sadly I don't really know Spring :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App Service, the front-ends are offloading the SSL. For Tomcat and WildFly images we added a filter that takes care of hydrating the context at the web worker machine.

Unfortunately, in cases when the customer brings their own Web Server such as Spring Boot, they will need to add custom logic like the one from our filters to workaround this.

Other option, is to rely on App Service to do the authentication by using App Service EasyAuth feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

Answer (score 2):

With the new [azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory/aad-web-application) dependency for Spring you can add the `azure.activedirectory.redirect-uri-template` property.

Example `application.yml`:

```
azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: <id>
    client-id: <id>
    client-secret: <secret>
    redirect-uri-template: https://app.example.com/login/oauth2/code/
```

#### Update for Spring-Cloud-Azure Version 4.x

Example `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        enabled: true
        profile:
          tenant-id: <tenant_id>
        credential:
          client-id: <client_id>
          client-secret: <secret>
        redirect-uri-template: https://app.example.com/login/oauth2/code/
```

Comment: what if after authentication we want to redirect to dashboard page, with this it will not redirect to some meaningful page

Comment: This working solution will redirect you to whatever URL you have requested before the autentication happens. So if you want to redirect to dashboard, you have to do it in the usual "spring-way". You might as well describe your specific error in a new question and I will try to solve it with you.